# Setting the GUID for a virtual machine inn ESXI server with vSphere Client

Tags: esxi

I clone a virtual machine from an existing one. I want to set the GUID parameter shown in the following picture.
[image: boot screen]

For this I try to edit the machine parameters here.

[image: edit]

I do this as per [VMWare Documentation](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1541).

But after I click OK on both dialog boxes and if I open it again I don't see the value again in this 'Configuration Parameters' dialog here. I haven't checked the error logs from ESXI server because I don't know how to.

But I would like to know if this is some operation that cannot be done from vSphere. The documentation above is about manually editing the .vmx file. I'm not sure if I can do this from EsXI server because I only have limited knowledge/access to it.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I change the values with the VM switched off

Comment: Is the VM running while you're trying to apply the change? If so, try stopping it before making the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do this via a C# utility using the Vmware APIs (`ReconfigVM` API).

```
var cs = new VirtualMachineConfigSpec();
cs.Uuid = "00 88 22 33 44 55 66 77-88 99 aa bb cc dd ee ff";
Vm.ReconfigVM(cs);
```

This is working fine for me.